# Set TextView To Right Of LinearLayout(Vertical)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I've been searching all over the Google for this answer. I've been trying to set a TextView to align with the right of my vertical LinearLayout. However, setting the params and using this...

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

doesn't work. I'm almost certain it is because I have set the width to WRAP_CONTENT.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

The problem is, if I set the width to MATCH_PARENT then (as expected) the background color of the TextView fills the whole width of the screen. I am not trying to set the gravity of the text to the right. I'm trying to get the whole TextView to align with the right of the LinearLayout while keeping the width equal to the size of the text inside it.

Can anyone help???

Comment: where is your vertical LinearLayout. ?

Comment: Please show the XML or Java code which creates the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` does not work because it is a rule for `RelativeLayout`, not for `LinearLayout`

Presuming your LinearLayout is set to `match_parent` then you should apply gravity. Just add the following to the TextView

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

The programmatic equivalent being to adjust the layout params on the TextView:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.END; //despite the confusing name, this is on Layout params and this is layout_gravity
params.weight = 1.0f;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Note**: Layout Gravity and View Gravity are different things - Layout Gravity sets the views position within it's layout, whereas gravity sets the gravity for the content within the view

Comment: Great, glad it helped. The thanks are appreciated but, as you are a new user I'll just say when you want to thank someone on SO it's intended that you show it by upvoting and/or accepting their answer

Comment: Tried to upvote and I cant because of my reputation but just noticed I can accept the answer like you said! Thanks a ton!